# How to implement cXML in Dynamics Axapta 2012 for VendInvoice AIF service

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, cxml-commercexml

We have a request to automatize the process of Vend Invoice creation in Dynamics axapta 2012.

The request is to add a customization to be able to create vend invoices using Inbound port AccountsPayable from cXML's.

Does anybody know whit what process to start?
Do we have to create a intermediate service which will parse cXML file in XML and to call axapta vend invoice service?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your schema defined in your cXML schema and you want to use the standard AIF schema, you'll have to transform your file. You can use .net or XSLT transform in AX or use a middleware before to do the transform.
You need to look at the schemas to choose the better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Just a question : On Client side we added a service reference to our service. Do you know how to send cxml direcltly to our create action?

Comment: Just to be sure, you created a .NET proxy on an external service? If so, you can manipulate it directly from X++ code.

Comment: Yes - we created a custom .NET external service. This service will parse cXML into Service schema service and will insert messages in an external database. AIF is configured to read messages from external databases. Do you know a good parser from cXML format? of we have to write our own parser?  We plan to convert the cXML to 'AIF format'