# Dynamics AX cXML Shopping Protocol

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, cxml-commercexml

In the process of setting up of an External Vendor Catalog in AX, but I'm met with some issues.  Based on what is required by the vendor for connection, I should be using cXML for this connection.  I've added the required info but not sure what I'm doing wrong and haven't found any solid information on this topic.

Given that the vendor requires cXML as the shopping protocol, I'm expecting that cXML would be an available option.  However, I'm only finding AXCI  in the listing.  Is there somewhere I'd need to go to enable or setup cXML?  Found really vague info that I may need to setup a custom class.  Any material out there on how to go about setting up an external vendor (with some details)?

Regards

Comment: There was already a discussion on cXML which AX which may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960120/how-to-implement-cxml-in-dynamics-axapta-2012-for-vendinvoice-aif-service/33983254#33983254

Answer (score 0):

I guess you assume that AX directly should support cXML. [It does not](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/135477).

It can output the AX in-house XML and you can apply XSLT transformations on that.